# If we have the repo local import it, else download via maven

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to update our gradle script to see if we have a local instance of a repo. Otherwise to download it. In essence we the developers do not want to push to maven as we work on our shared repos locally. However our as part of our deployment pipeline our tools will need to pull it. We are not too worried about the repo getting stale yet. However I am not sure how to write this statement.

The current solution is to always pull the repo. Again the goal is to have a bit more control and not need to sync with our repo.

```
configurations.all {
    // check for updates every build
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
}

 compile ('com.aaaa.commons:1.2.3') { changing=true }
```

Desire

```
if(path/to/project exists){
  import the local dependency
}
else{
  compile ('com.aaaa.commons:1.2.3') { changing=true }
}
```

EDIT

The issue is that requires me to import it as a module. Which is essentially coping it into my application. Which is exactly what I do not want. If i do a

```
include ':commons'
project(':commons').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir,
    '/Users/asdasd/Repos/android-commons')
```

we get

```
   Error:Project :app declares a dependency from configuration 'compile' to configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :commons.
```

EDIT EDIT
I needed to select one more down in the file tree.. I had my libraries root selected. I needed commons not android commons.

```
mymainproject
android-commons
    android-commons.iml
    build
    build.gradle
    **commons**
```

From there I could not actually use the library till I compiled it like (note I am doing debug as release will pull it always)

```
 debugCompile project(path: ':commons')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple approach I used from time to time:

```
try {
    compile project(':my-project')
} catch (UnknownProjectException) {
    compile 'com.aaaa.ooooo:1.2.3'
}
```

However, I am not sure whether there is a better solution using the `resolutionStrategy`. One drawback: If the other project can be found, it won't be added as a dependency when publishing your project to a repository.

It may be neccessary to add a condition to the project inclusion in the `setting.gradle` file like below:

```
if (new File(rootDir, 'my-project').isDirectory()) {
    include ':my-project'
}
```

Comment: Very interesting. Though the main issue is that if I try add the module with  include ':commons' in my top level settings.gradle, it will create an empty directory in the application with that name. I am trying your code in app/build.gradle

Comment: I've added an example for conditionary project inclusion in `settings.gradle` to my answer.